# Why does the AppClassLoader delegate to the ExtClassLoader instead of BootstrapClassLoader?

Tags: java, class, jvm, classloader

I learn that

> Bootstrap ClassLoader loads classes from the location rt.jar.

and the `Delegation Model`

```
Bootstrap
|
Extensions
|
Application
```

When I look at AppClassLoader, it is
Static classes in sun.misc.Lanucher under `jre\lib\rt.jar`

As mentioned above, BootstrapClassLoader will load the classes under the rt.jar package, that is to say, the loading class of `AppClassLoader` is `BootstrapClassLoader`

so why does AppClassLoader delegate to the static inner class ExtClassLoader `under the same class` instead of BootstrapClassLoader?

Comment: Whether these class loaders are implemented using nested classes or top level classes or whether they are in the same outer class or not, is entirely irrelevant to the delegation model. In fact, both loaders could be instances of the same class and it wouldn’t affect the delegation logic.

Comment: @Holger Sorry, what I mean is, BootstrapClassLoader loads the classes under the `rt.jar` package, and AppClassLoader and ExtClassLoader are both internal static classes of sum.misc.Launcher under the rt.jar package, which means they are both `The class under the rt.jar package`, so the loading class of these two classes should be BootstrapClassLoader.

The delegation model requires that the loading class is delegated to the `parent class loader` when handling the loading of the class, so why does `ExtClassLoader become the parent` class loader of AppClassLoader

Comment: You are trying to conflate entirely unrelated things. The location of a class doesn’t say anything about what a class is doing. Further, you are confusing objects and classes. As said, both loaders could be instances of the same class and it still would work. Just like a [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Properties)) instance can be the parent of another `Properties` instance. It doesn’t matter that it’s the same class, because delegation happens between objects and these are different objects.